# Can't able to start new activity from onPostExecute method in Android

Tags: java, android

Here is my Java code. My problem is when I add some code to `OnPostExecute` to open another activity. I'm new to Android Studio so I'm facing this problem for first time.

```
package com.example.gonalo.meu;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import static android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivity;
import static android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startActivities;

 /**
* Created by Gonçalo on 23/03/2016.
*/

public class BackGroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackGroundWorker (Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://192.168.1.79/login.php";
    String register_url = "http://192.168.1.79/register.php";
    //String verifyuserpass_url = "http://192.168.0.102/verifyuserpass.php";
    //String verifypass_url = "http://192.168.0.102/verifyuserpass.php";
    if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            String user = URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8");//guarda o nome de utilizador introduzido
            String pass = URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");//guarda a pass introduzido
            System.err.println("------------------------------------------");
             /*/  if(user.equals("Nome de Utilizador")){
                   if(pass.equals("Password")) {
                       System.err.println("Entrou no if");
                       startActivity(new Intent(this, Pagina1.class));}
 /*/
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result +=line;

            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else if(type.equals("register")) {
        try {
            String name = params[1];
            String surname = params[2];
            String age = params[3];
            String username = params[4];
            String password = params[5];
            URL url = new URL(register_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("surname", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(surname, "UTF-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("age", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(age, "UTF-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;

                }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return null;
}



@Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
    if (result.equals("Login Success"));
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Pagina1.class); // Im facing problem here
    startActivity(myIntent); // Im facing problem here

}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

[Start Activity error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Woj.png)

[Cannot resolve constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9UMn.png)

I'm trying to add some simple code and my Android does not recognize it.

Comment: See the images that i uploaded to understand my problem.

Comment: Does it work now bro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bro, your problem is that you're passing `this` in the Intent, and `this` is currently the `AsyncTask` which is **NOT** derived from anything that has `Context` (Activities have Context). Just replace that line with this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, Pagina1.class));}
//context being the field you initialize in the constructor
```

And this'll work.
I know you have probably found somewhere that this is the correct way to start the activity:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(this, YourClass.class));
```

Which it is, when it is from another `Activity`, because the first parameter of the `Intent()` constructor is `Context`, which activities do have. `Fragments`, `AsyncTasks`, etc. are not derived from `Context` and therefore you cannot just call `this` when you're trying to `startActivity` from them.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem!  Your the best bro.

Comment: Sure thing mate. Best of luck in your following endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Pagina1.class);

In above statement **this** point to the current class object not, activity or context of application. You must give the context of application. Because the current class is not an activity. Above statement should become like this

Try this statement

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Pagina1.class);
```

Replace above statement in your `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: Why would he `getApplicationContext()` when he could just use the `Context context` field in the `AsyncTask`? Also, I've already answered that :D

Answer (score 0):

In onPostExecute method do the following:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

It will surely work!